# Starting and stopping sound AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm trying to get a sound thats on the timeline to stop and play when i push the buttons. And there is also a animation on that timeline that should stop and play to.  I cant get the code that im using to work. I get errors

Del1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 16 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method play through a reference with static type flash.media:SoundChannel.

Del1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 10 1120: Access of undefined property fireworks.

I'm new to this I have no idea how to fix the errors and get the buttons to work.

here is the entire code

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;


PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playbutton);
NextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextbutton);
StopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopbutton);

var mySound:Sound = new fireworks.wav(); 
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
myChannel = mySound.play();

function playbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
{
myChannel.play();
play(); 
}

function stopbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
{
stop();
myChannel.stop();
}

function nextbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(1, "Del2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your first error: You cannot call `play()` on a `SoundChannel`**

Although you can always `stop()` your `myChannel` object, you can not as simply play it. See the section titled Pausing a Sound in [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/) for information on the functionality that you are trying to build. Essentially, when you pause your song, you need to remember that location in the song, and then call `myChannel = mySound.play(thatLocation);` whenever you want to resume.

**Your second error: The syntax on adding your song file needs to be changed a bit**

If the song file is somewhere outside of Flash, like in a folder -

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("fireworks.wav"));
mySound.play();
```

If the song file is loaded into your Flash library -

```
var mySound:Sound = new CustomSongNameHere();
mySound.play();
```

But for this case, you *need* to find the song in your Flash library, right-click it, select `Linkage`, check `Export for ActionScript` and change the `Class` field to `CustomSongNameHere` or whatever you use in your code.